# Drop shadow on fragments with a listview and scrollview

Tags: java, android

I'm having an issue with a ListView and a ScrollView and adding a drop shadow between the listview and the ScrollView.

I had made a shape, which works great with a ListView and a relative layout, but does not work with the ScrollView.

I have done the following - Dashboard List

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">
     <ListView 
               android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"
               android:listSelector="#31ABD4"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="No data"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Dashboard with scroll view

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_left" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

View

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:angle="180"
        android:width="10dp"
        android:centerX="0.1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="#55000000"
        android:type = "linear"

        />
</shape>
```

**Edit - Attached Screenshots**

[image: What I want - Got that working without ScrollView]
[image: With ScrollView]

Thank you all,
James

Comment: can you post a current and expected result in a picture

Comment: The pictures you have uploaded doesn't describe that much.. Can you tell what is what, and also if you have a big picture of how you want it to look all together in the end, that would be very helpfull

Comment: in the attached image is that what it look right now?

Comment: Sorry I thought I had put comments on it - The image on the left is with a relative layout with a view after it. The image on the right is what it currently looks like, but I want it to look like the image on he left.

Comment: @JamesReeves  Your question isn't clear, you are not clearly stating what you are trying to achieve.  You start by saying that you somehow want to "adding a drop shadow between the listview and the ScrollView" and then you have two different layouts, one with a ListView and no shadow and one with a ScrollView and a View in it. So how can a shadow be "between"?   What's the relation between the ScrollView and the ListView? What are you actually trying todo? what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

seems that you are missing the paddings on "Dashboard with scroll view"

try this instead

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" >
        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_left" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```